# Why are these two recurrence relations that compute the shortest path equal?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

Given a directed graph $G=(V,E)$ with positive weight function $w$, source  $s$, destination $t$ and a nonnegative integer $\ell$, we want to find shortest path $\pi$ from $s$ to $t$ such that $\pi$ contains at most $\ell$ edges.

Let $d_{u,v}^\ell$ be the length of the shortest path between $u$ and $v$ with at most $\ell$ edges.

Here are the base cases.
$$\begin{equation}
  d_{u,v}^\ell=\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $ u= v$},\\
    w(u,v), & \text{else if } \ell=1 \wedge (u,v)\text{ is an edge}, \\
    \infty, & \text{else if } \ell=1 \wedge (u,v)\text{ is not an edge}. \\
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

I have two recursive formulas for $\ell\ge2$ and $u\not=v$.

$$
I:\;\;\;d_{u,v}^\ell=\min_{x\in V}(d_{u,x}^{\lceil{\frac{\ell}{2}}\rceil}+d_{x,v}^{\lfloor{\frac{\ell}{2}}\rfloor})
$$

$$II:\;\;\; d_{u,v}^\ell=
    \min_{x\in V}(d_{u,v}^{\ell-1},d_{u,x}^{\lceil{\frac{\ell}{2}}\rceil}+d_{x,v}^{\lfloor{\frac{\ell}{2}}\rfloor})
$$

The question is, can we claim that $I=II$, i.e., both relations find the optimal path? My teacher says $II$ is wrong. I think $II$ is correct but I have no proof.

Comment: What would be $d^1_{u,v}$ for $u,v$ that **aren't** neighbors?

Comment: Will be $\infty$.

Comment: Maybe the teacher referred to some computational aspect of this recurrence? The first is definitely easier to use when calculating

Comment: Think you $I=II$? Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "$I=II$"? Do you mean that for every $u,v,\ell$, the two definitions agree? Have you tried proving it by induction? If your attempts failed, have you tried constructing a counterexample, based on the way in which the proof failed?

Comment: I try find a counter example but I get stuck to find an example that $II$ doesn't work.

Comment: I think each relation finds optimal solution, but I can't prove it. Can you give me more hint that, how I can use induction on $\ell$?

Comment: Try to use induction on $\ell$ to prove the claim "for all $u,v$, $d_{u,v}^\ell$ is the length of the shortest path from $u$ to $v$ using at most $\ell$ edges".